# Spring data repository methods implementation

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I'm working in a personal web project and I would like to use Spring Data and JPA. I found [this nice blog entry](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/10/getting-started-with-spring-data-jpa/) in springsource.com and I've spent several hours trying to understand how this work and why they do it this way. I need help with two questions mainly:

1. Why is necesary to use Service and ServiceImpl classes. That seems like a typical JPA 2 implementation but using Spring Data underneath with an Autowired repository. This really confuse me. Why not use the repository directly?
2. The writer defines a pair of new methods in CustomerRepository but there isn't any implementation. He continues implementing CustomerService that it's not related with the repository. I've seen this in many sites but I don't understand how it works.

As I said I've been looking for a good article to find answers to my questions but most of them seem that are following these one. I've also checked github code of the article's project but it's uncomplete. I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of the blog post is to talk about spring-data repositories. So it doesn't elaborate on why services are necessary.

They are because a typical business method will deal with several DAOs/Repositories, in a single transaction. For example, transferring money might include calling the AccountRepository, the AudiRepository and the CustomerRepository. The service's main goal is to provide transactional business methods to the presentation layer.

Comment: Oh! I see. And what about the Repository method implementation? Why there isn't implementation for the method Page<Customer> findByLastname(String lastname, Pageable pageable); The author use it directly without define the body first.

Comment: That's the whole point of the blog post, and the beauty of spring-data. Spring dynamically creates a bean implementing the interface for you. You define the methods by following a set of conventions. You annotate the methods to specify the JPQL when needed, and Spring does the rest for you.

Comment: But does Spring define the method body also? Really interesting and impresive... Thank you very much for your help ;)

Comment: I've been thinking in your answer about Service classes and looking for examples about that but I don't find anything well explained. Could you point me to a good one?